# How to select customers that have ordered 3 diferrent product, but not a fourth?

Tags: mysql, prestashop

I have this SQL query that let me know when the customer have ordered a certain product :

```
SELECT * FROM ps_customer c
INNER JOIN ps_orders o ON (c.id_customer=o.id_customer)
INNER JOIN ps_order_detail od ON(od.id_order=o.id_order)
WHERE od.product_id=1
```

I'd like to get the customers that have order product 1, 2, 3, but never 4.

I can't simply make `WHERE od.product_id IN (1, 2, 3) AND od.product_id != 4`, but I'm stuck on how to build that query correctly.

For information, the database structure is a basic Prestashop (1.6.1.4) datastore.

Here's the SQLFiddle :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfd65

(I can't add the data, it's too much for SQLFiddle ...)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you should think differently

```
SELECT * FROM ps_customer c
INNER JOIN ps_orders o ON (c.id_customer=o.id_customer)
INNER JOIN ps_order_detail od ON(od.id_order=o.id_order)
WHERE od.product_id IN (1, 2, 3)  and c.id_customer NOT IN (select id_customer from ps_orders where product_id IN (4) )
```

Comment: I'm curious about the -1, I just tried it and it seems to work correctly ?

Comment: Now I'm curious too. why -1. any one can explain ?

Comment: I've been able to extensively test it, and I discovered that the "IN (1, 2, 3)" work as a "or" clause : Some results have only product_id 1 or 2 or 3, where I need them to be ALL (1 AND 2 AND 3). Do you have an idea?

Comment: you can use od.product_id =1 and  od.product_id =2 and  od.product_id =3 
but it will not work because at a time product has only one id

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Comment: use this answer if you don't understand let me know   http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45512/how-do-i-select-items-from-a-table-where-a-single-column-must-contain-two-or-mo

Comment: Awesome, it worked, I needed to add the HAVING clause. You can add it here to make the answer correct if you want.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a couple of dinaminc table  join on id_customer

```
  select * from (  
        SELECT id_customer 
        FROM ps_customer c
        INNER JOIN ps_orders o ON c.id_customer=o.id_customer
        INNER JOIN ps_order_detail od ON od.id_order=o.id_order 
        WHERE od.product_id  <> 4  ) t1
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id_customer FROM ps_customer c
    INNER JOIN ps_orders o ON c.id_customer=o.id_customer
    INNER JOIN ps_order_detail od ON od.id_order=o.id_order 
    WHERE od.product_id in ( 1,2,3)
    having count(distinct(od.product_id)) =3
    ) t2 on t1.id_customer = t2.id_customer
```

Comment: This one is near what I need. The only odd thing is that when I change the first query from 4 to an other bought product_id (say 5), the query return the customer_id, even though he had purchased product 1, 2, 3, 5. In that case, the result should not contain that customer.

Comment: @CyrilN.   . the first dinamic query  is based  on your question. you sai not  one prduct .. if you need  more than a product excluded  you should do like in second  dinamic  query  adding a having condition on then number of distinct product excluded ..and search for <> user .. answer updated  ..

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough. I really want to exclude only one product. Product ID 4 hasn't been bought by the customer, but product ID 5 has been. If, in your first query, I change the `WHERE od.product_id <> 4`, to `WHERE od.product_id <> 5`, the customer is returned, and it should not, since that customer has bought product id 5. Am I clearer?

Comment: this is strange  beacuse  .. the firts should return only the customer that have not bought a product and the inner join  .between the two dinamic query is on ..  the customer_id  .. so if is not in the first can be joined  with the second .. ( i  have update the asnwer  because there are some mistake and a wrong NOT)

Comment: Yes, and I'm sorry, I can't paste the data to SQLFiddle, I reach the limit :/

Comment: @scaisEdge you can see my answer. why are you using all join to get only customer ids who brought product id=4 ? you also get customer id in same table